# Changing Background Color Of Image in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Can we Change the background color on an Image in Flutter? Like in this Image I want to change the pink color background color to something else.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to actually trying  to achieve. Image editing or just widget background

Comment: please add some more information.

Comment: like this image has black rectangle I want to change it into a different color. so that I can paint with different color pattern without using many images.

Comment: my case i wanted something different, i wanted to display background color to an image which looks perfect on that image, meaning the color that dominate the image to be it. Like on tweeter

Comment: i have a transparent background png image and want to set background color to white and save image into jpg format. How can i do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do that with flutter. You need an image editor to change the background color.

If you want to change the background color dynamically you will first have to make the background transparent by adding an alpha channel mask to the image (again using an image editor) 
You will then be able to define a background color by putting the image inside a widget that has a background color.

Here is a complete example app. The background color changes at random when the widget is reloaded.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Color randomColor() =>
      Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt() << 0).withOpacity(1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: randomColor(),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.stack.imgur.com/O02Ip.png',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am decoding the image and applying the color and again encoding it but it is not working properly... I am taking help with this [plugin](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples)

Comment: You don't need a third party plugin to change the background color of the image. I have extended my code example into a complete example app that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: i had applied this ..in my case color changes everytime i tap on something or in every hot reload @Soundbytes

Comment: @urvashi You are correct. The bg-color changes whenever the widget is redrawn. 
To achieve the originally claimed behaviour you would have to use a MyApp member variable and reset that in the initializer. I have added your correction to my original article.

Comment: i have a transparent background png image and want to set background color to white and save image into jpg format. How can i do?

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was trying to color a **Transparent PNG**

I tried [this solution](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-make-a-png-gradient-overlay-in-flutter-bcdfb922e3ed) and it's working.

Using ShaderMask class (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html)

Example:

```
ShaderMask(
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage("assets/cat.png"),
  ),
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
    return LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.lightBlue],
      stops: [
        0.0,
        0.5,
      ],
    ).createShader(bounds);
  },
  blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
)
```

Comment: i have a transparent background png image and want to set background color to white and save image into jpg format. How can i do?

Answer (score 6):

I know that's an old question, but for those that came from google.

It's now possible, since flutter 1.9, using the widget ColorFiltered.

```
 body: Center(
        child: ColorFiltered(
          child:Image.network(
                      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/14/07/21/mountain-4694346_960_720.png",
                    ),
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.color),
        
      ),
```

Full example,  By Rashid:
https://flutterforyou.com/how-to-change-color-of-an-image-in-flutter/

Answer (score 1):

By wrapping the image into a **container** then adding colour inside of SVG file and by using the **flutter_svg** package there is a colour argument that will fill the color of your choice

```
                       child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle
                            ),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/plus.svg',
                            color: Color(0xff280D78)),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution. So, you can contain the widget and then decorate the container with a color.

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(imageLink),
                ),
              
            ),
          ),
```

**You don't need the borderRadius but in my case I used ClipRRect with borderRadius.**

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to add color to a background for a **Transparent PNG**

This can be done by using a **stack widget** as below follows:

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
     Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       height: double.infinity,
       margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
       color: Colors.blue[500],
     ),
     Image.asset(
       'images/frame.png',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
     ),
   ],
 )
```

I added a margin so the colored background was only seen inside my photo frame image.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Widget removewhitefromImage({Widget? child, List<Color>? listofcolors}) {
  return ShaderMask(
    child: child ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
    shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
      return LinearGradient(
        colors: listofcolors ?? [AppColors.cardColor, AppColors.cardColor],
      ).createShader(bounds);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).