# How to pass image asset in imageprovider type?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, assets

I currently depend on *splashscreen 1.2.0* package for the a flutter app.
But the *backgroundimage* variable type is *imageprovider*, whereas I want to use the image from assets folder. Does anyone know how to pass the image asset file to be able to use as the *imageprovider* type or maybe any other way to make it work?

Cause using the *imageprovider* it just loaded a bit later on compared to the other properties.

Many thanks!

I've tried using the Image.asset() but didn't work.

```
return SplashScreen(
    seconds: 5,
    navigateAfterSeconds: AppRoute,
    title: Text('Welcome', style: AppTextStyle),
    image: Image.asset(AppAsset.logo),
    photoSize: AppScreen,
    imageBackground: Image.asset(AppAsset.background),
    loaderColor: AppColor,
    loadingText: Text('Loading'),
    styleTextUnderTheLoader: AppTextStyle,
    onClick: () {},
 );
```

Expected to be able to use Image.assets but it only works for the network image.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try changing the `Image.asset(AppAsset.background)` to as follows

`Image.asset(AppAsset.background).image`

Or

`AssetImage(AppAsset.background)`

Comment: It works, thanks so much mate! You're awesome!
Btw is possible to add Color blend mode as well in it?

Comment: @leemuljadi check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922775/changing-background-color-of-image-in-flutter#answers, i haven't tried

Comment: I ended up using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190657/flutter-how-to-blend-an-image-with-a-gradient-colour)
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.srcOver),
  child: YourWidget(),
) 
Thanks mate for the advise!

Comment: The first one works, thanks. The second one does not, since compiler does not automatically consider `AssetImage` to be an `ImageProvider` (probably because of generalization), and using of `as` operator is discouraged.