# PNG image background turns black after save

Tags: image, flutter, dart, png

Potential copy of the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922775/changing-background-color-of-image-in-flutter): Tried the solution but didn't work

I'm working on a image coloring application in flutter which lets the user color a black outlined image and save it.

Now I've downloaded quite a few PNG images which seems regular but once added to flutter assets folder shows a black tiled background.

Once added to **gallery** screen which lets the user choose any image they want application shows a perfectly normal image. But after coloring the image when I'm saving the image I see a black back ground.

**Here's an opened in vs code**

[image]

**Here's the image selection screen which shows a perfectly normal bird: **

[image]

**And here's the image after saving:**

[image]

Now comes the coding part.

This here is my display image portion:

```
Widget displayImage(BuildContext context, String providedImagePath) {
    return Container(
      // child: Container(
      //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      //     color: Colors.white,
      //   ),
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage(providedImagePath),
        // color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),
        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      //),
    );
```

The comment out part is from other stack overflow answers that I tried but didn't work.

And here is the save function:

```
  Future<void> _save() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    //Request permissions if not already granted
    if (!(await Permission.storage.status.isGranted))
      await Permission.storage.request();

    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(pngBytes),
        quality: 60,
        name: "henlo");
    print(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably somewhere between

```
boundary.toImage();
```

and

```
byteData.buffer.asUnit8List();
```

I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but you can remove the background again, try this as a workaround https://gist.github.com/plateaukao/ebb5e7169dd89cc52bda338762d4997e